# Using CN1 bluetooth is not scanning devices on Android

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I compiled the BTDemo with Netbeans fine (downloaded the APK from CN1 build servers).

Then I installed it on an Android LG phone and an Android Tablet, both enables the Bluetooth fine, but do not scan anything.

I got response {"status":"scanStarted"} when I click on startScan button.
(res.length = 1)

Is this BTDemo code working for anyone?

Using this demo code: https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone

Comment: Notice that this is BluetoothLE not old bluetooth. Do you have any such devices around?

Comment: I'm working with it, there are some tricky spots and I haven't figured it all out yet, though. Please tell us what type of device you're trying to connect to, also what Android version(s).